# py3.6 win10 - error installing virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows-10, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Just installed Py3.6, made sur pip is installed and tried to install virtualenv with:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

And this is the result:

```
pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "c:\program files\python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv.py'
```

Same thing happened when I tried:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: python -m pip install virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command from a command prompt having admin privileges

On Windows 8 and 10 you can just press Windows+X and on the menu, choose "Command Prompt (Admin)"

This question is possibly a copy of [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044298/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-c-program-files-python35-lib)