# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\six.py'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, permissions

I am using python 3.5.3, and now I want to install pandas and numpy but not able to, following is the error in cmd, anyone can help me?

```
 C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts>py -3.5 -m pip install pandas 

Collecting pandas
Using cached pandas-0.20.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2 (from pandas)
Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas)
Using cached numpy-1.12.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
Using cached pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)
Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, numpy, pytz, pandas
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\six.py'
```

Comment: Make sure you are running that command from a command line with administrator privileges.

Comment: can give some example? sorry I don't get what you mean

Comment: @ShiJieTio It looks like you're using windows. Instead of just launching Command Prompt, right click the icon and then click on "Run as administrator". From there, run your pip command and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As others have pointed out you need to run the command with admin privileges.

How to do this [varies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx#Anchor_0) by windows version, but on Windows 8 and 10 you can just press Windows+X (or just right-clicking the Start button). On the menu, choose “Command Prompt (Admin).”

Comment: Thanks Duncan, your suggestion helped me to get over this issue... appreciate your suggestion that, how to open command prompt in Windows 10 with admin privileges...

Comment: I unfortunately still get the same error although working from an administrator command line :/

Answer (score 4):

The command line you're using does not have access to `C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\six.py`.

Run the command in a command line with administrative priveleges.

Answer (score 0):

Run command line in admin mode and then :

```
pip instal pandas
```