# PermissionError during installing Keras library in Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I'm getting `PermissionError` during the installation of Keras on Windows. Here's the console log:

```
(base) C:\Users\nEW u>pip install --upgrade keras
Collecting keras
  Using cached Keras-2.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scipy>=0.14 (from keras)
  Using cached scipy-1.0.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pyyaml in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.9.0 in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages 
(from keras)
Collecting numpy>=1.9.1 (from keras)
  Using cached numpy-1.14.2-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, keras
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.13.3
    Uninstalling numpy-1.13.3:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk 
drive: 'e:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy' -> 
'C:\\Users\\NEWU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-h2l8dzqf-
uninstall\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in 
uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in 
remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in 
renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 556, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'e:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
```

Comment: Try `conda install keras`

Comment: no its not working

Comment: try `sudo equivalent on windows`. you are getting permission issue. start cmd with admin privileges, or try to do this from anaconda shell instead of cmd if you are using cmd.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the command line in administrator in order to get access to those directories. it has been answered in another post:

[PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\six.py'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044298/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-c-program-files-python35-lib?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

hope it works.